# ALTER TABLE AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: php, mysql

I am having  a problem with ALTER TABLE AUTO-INCREMENT. it does altered the table to 100 but it does not auto-increment. hope anyone can help me.. here is my code. thanks in advance.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","info"); 
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql= "ALTER TABLE profile AUTO_INCREMENT=100";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

if (isset ($_POST['Register!']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO staff_profile (name, age, address) 
    VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$address')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Are any error's generated when you run the script? it is important to note that if you reset a column to autoincrment at a value lower than the MAX value of that column, the next auto increment value will be `1 + MAX(COLUMN)`.  Please provide more details about your table structure.

Comment: Have you actually set a column to `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: nope. but the primary key is only 100 and it does not increment. and if i run the script to key in the next data, it displayed duplicate '100'

Comment: `ALTER TABLE profile CHANGE i i INT( 10 ) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT = 100`

Comment: Marcel Gwerder , yes, I hve set the column

Comment: What's the difference between `staff_profile` and `profile`? I'm confused, are you expecting the insert statement in the above code to get an auto incremented value? Because then it's strange when you alter a different table.

Comment: So did you, or did you not set the column in question to auto_increment?  In one comment you stated "nope" and in another you said yes. From the sounds of things, you haven't actually set the column to auto_increment. However, if it's a primary key, and it's duplicating the keys of '100' you have a bigger problem.

Comment: I have set the column to auto_increment. Nope=there is no error. hehe. Marcel Gwerder, sorry, actually it was staff_profile and im altering the same table. error copied.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you must specify the column name upon which you implemented the auto increment clause..

```
ALTER TABLE tbl 
    CHANGE itemid itemid INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

The above statement will change the `itemid` column to datatype `INT`, make it AUTO INCREMENT, and make it the primary key as well.

Now, you can set the initial value of auto_increment clause by following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Comment: sorry, what is itemid itemid INT(10) for?

Comment: we change previous "itemid" to new "itemid" which is int, auto_increment, and most important.. primary key

Comment: do I hve to assign it to a variable for example     $sql= "ALTER TABLE profile AUTO_INCREMENT=100"; ?

Comment: because if not, i will get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TABLE' (T_STRING)

Comment: assign it to a coloumn.. Don't you have any primary key in table.. If not.. do this:
alter table profile add profile_id int not null auto_increment

Comment: I have an ID as a primary key.